# Action bar tabs set background remove tab indicators

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I was trying to change the color of action bar tab background through styles. but after changing the background successfully. Tab indicators are disappeared. Any one have any idea why is that.

Here is style.xml

```
<style name="Theme.myTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/customActionBarTabStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/customActionBarTabStyle</item>

</style>

<style name="customActionBarTabStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="background">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/white </item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. I should have not set background for tab. Color white will set the background white and remove everything.